# Looping through pandas data frame while changing row values using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, pandas, for-loop

---

*-EDIT-*

As Daniel Kasatchkow (below) suggested, I have attempted the following:

```
df._links.str.findall('qwer://abc\\\.x-data\\\.orc/v1/i/\d+/users')
```

But I get the following output:

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
...
```

UPDATE - Still unable  to find a solution

Comment: is it `link_re` or `regex_l` ?

Comment: Your regex pattern will need to escape the \ and `.` characters. Also, generally you will need to capture your match with parentheses.

Comment: @moogle Alright. I don't believe that resolves the looping issue.

Comment: @BenF97 Well, it looks like you're trying to regex a dictionary, so instead you'll need to navigate down so that you're regexing a string `'qwer://...'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(["{u'users': {u'href': u'qwer://abc\.x-data\.orc/v1/i/32/users'}, u'self': {u'href': ...","{u'users': {u'href': u'qwer://abc\.x-data\.orc/v1/i/87/users'}, u'self': {u'href': ..."], columns=['_links'])

df._links.str.findall('qwer://abc\\\.x-data\\\.orc/v1/i/\d+/users')
```

When using regex I find it helpful to trial out the regex on http://pythex.org/

If the data is in a dictionary format, it would be best to convert it over to a DataFrame using [pandas.DataFrame.from_dict](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)